# How to convert PVOID to int?

Tags: c++, mfc, safearray

I got a function :

`SAFEARRAY FAR* pArray = NULL;`

and I get that function :
`pServer1->GetDirectMemory(dwAddrBegin, dwAddrEnd, wDisplayWidth, &pArray);`

I want to get information from pArray, if i look the structure of it, I have `PVOID pvData;` that must be contains my information.

How could I get it in a int ?

**Old question :**

I want to get the data of a PVOID to a int value

I get a `SAFEARRAY FAR* pArray` and I have only one element so I get ir with a PVOID type like that :

```
PVOID myData = pArray[0].pvData;
```

And I try to get the data with the function PtrToInt :

```
int myNbr = PtrToInt(myData);
```

But my int (myNbr) doens't get the same value that i can see with my debugger.
So my question is how can i get datas from that `SAFEARRAY FAR* pArray` or `PVOID` without using MFC function like `SafeArrayAccessData` or else.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to cast a pointer to an int, eg `int p=reinterpret_cast<int>(ptr)` ?

Comment: `SafeArrayAccessData` is in the `OleAuto.h` header you shouldn't need to include MFC to access it.

Comment: I get an adress in my PVOID and I want to put the value where is a that adress, in a int variable

Comment: Your latest comment is unclear. A `PVOID` is a pointer, right? (I'm guessing it's a typedef for `void*`.) Do you want the pointer value converted to `int`, or do you want the value of the `int` object that it points to? If the former, that's rarely a useful thing to do, and depending on the system it can lose information. If the latter, why wasn't the pointer defined as an `int*` in the first place? (There can be good reasons to use `void*` to point to `int` data, but usually using an `int*` is the best approach.)

Comment: I use a PVOID because the structure `SAFEARRAY` was defined in using PVOID.

I got a int in the `SAFEARRAY FAR* pArray` and I cannot get the value to put it in a int

Comment: @Fred37b this question is **HIGHLY** unclear as to the exact circumstances of the problem you're facing. Can you update your question to include a minimum viable example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array contains ints (use `SafeArrayGetVartype` to verify), is 1-dimensional (use `SafeArrayGetDim`) and 0-based (use `SafeArrayGetLBound`), the correct way to access it is this:

```
int value;
LONG indices[] = { 0 };
if (FAILED(SafeArrayGetElement(pArray, indices, &value))) {
  // getting element failed - probably bad index
}
// value now contains the correct value
```

You can use `SafeArrayAccessData` too, but unless you have identified a performance problem, it's better not to.

In general when dealing with OLE structures (`VARIANT`, `SAFEARRAY`, etc.) you should always use the provided utility functions. They are part of Windows, not MFC. Here's the reference for arrays:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221145(v=vs.85).aspx

However, if you can, I strongly recommend you use ATL's wrapper for SAFEARRAY, CComSafeArray. See the documentation and a short blog article showing its usage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xzbsee8.aspx
http://msmvps.com/blogs/gdicanio/archive/2011/02/04/simplifying-safearray-programming-with-ccomsafearray.aspx

Comment: Thank for your answer.

Maybe it's not int because int does not contain the correct value.

Comment: I work with a µController which is on 16 bits when my computer is on 32 bits, so the µP send me a 16 bits int and my system don't see a int because for it, it must be on 32 bits. 

So i change the type of value from int to char and now i receive my variable.

Thanks for helping